# why we can download faster with IDM

Tags: networking, web, network-programming, social-networking

I have a question about downloading with IDM or without it

the question is, we have the same bandwidth and the server sharing same bandwidth

for IDM and simple downlaod manager.

but why we can download faster  with IDM? what is the reason?

TNX...

Comment: if you have any source about computer networking specially "different between download with connection oriented and connection less" or "ftp and tftp" please send it.. TNX

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without a download accelerator, you may not be hitting your and the remote server's bandwidth bottleneck. This means that either or both of you have still more bandwidth that can be tapped.

Download accelerators tap this extra bandwidth in two ways:

1. By increasing the number of connections to the server, IDM consumes
   all or maximum of your bandwidth and increases the proportion of your total internet bandwidth that goes to the download.
2. The remote server divides it's total bandwidth to the number of connections to it. So, multiple connections to the server ensure that the total bandwidth you're tapping is a sum of those divided bandwidths thus removing another bottleneck.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Download_manager#Download_acceleration for more.

Comment: The link is now a stub.

Comment: Also, how does the second one accelerate the download? If the bandwidth was originally 10 Mbps, having 2 connections would give you 2 x 5 Mbps which doesn't do anything to the bottleneck

Answer (score 2):

Typically a download manager accelerates by making multiple simultaneous connections to the remote server.  I believe IDM may actually make multiple requests to the same file at the same time, and thus trick the server into providing higher bandwidth through the multiple connections.  Servers are typically bandwidth limited on a per-connection basis, so by making multiple connections, you get higher total bandwidth.